# Azure AD : MSAL - Cypress Login : ClientAuthError - Invalid base64 string

Tags: azure-active-directory, base64, cypress, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

Trying to perform silent login from Cypress. While setting msal.client.info in local storage, getting an error "Invalid base64 string" and it's not login user to web application. Tried to add MSAL.clientInfo by importing @azure/msal-browser. But, no luck. Can you please guide, what's going wrong here.

```
import * as MSAL from "@azure/msal-browser"

Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
    cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${Cypress.config("tenantId")}/oauth2/token`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: Cypress.config("clientId"),
        client_secret: Cypress.config("clientSecret"),
        resource: Cypress.config("resource")
      },
    }).then(response => {
      const MSALToken = response.body.access_token;
      const expiresOn = response.body.expires_on;
      console.log("Body: " + JSON.stringify(response.body));
      window.localStorage.setItem("msal.token.keys", `${Cypress.config("clientId")}|`);
      window.localStorage.setItem(`msal.access.token.key${Cypress.config("clientId")}`, MSALToken);
      window.localStorage.setItem(`msal.expiration.key${Cypress.config("clientId")}`, expiresOn);
      window.localStorage.setItem("msal.idtoken", MSALToken);
      window.localStorage.setItem(`msal.client.info`, MSAL.clientInfo);
    });
  });
```

Response Received:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3599",
  "ext_expires_in": "3599",
  "expires_on": "1622095375",
  "not_before": "1622091475",
  "resource": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJh....BEFg"
}
```

Getting Error "Invalid base64 string" while setting

```
window.localStorage.setItem(`msal.client.info`, MSAL.clientInfo);


Unhandled Promise rejection: The client info could not be parsed/decoded correctly. Please review the trace to determine the root cause. Failed with error: Error: Invalid base64 string ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ClientAuthError: The client info could not be parsed/decoded correctly. Please review the trace to determine the root cause. Failed with error: Error: Invalid base64 string
    at e [as constructor] (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at new e (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at Function.e.createClientInfoDecodingError (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at new t (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at t.getAccount (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at t.checkAccount (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at new t (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at Object.FG+x.t.ɵfac [as factory] (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at Nr.hydrate (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1)
    at Nr.get (VM19 main-es2015.5d1f7b11d6a7d9a05ff5.js:1) ClientAuthError: The client info could not be parsed/decoded correctly. Please review the trace to determine the root cause. Failed with error: Error: Invalid base64 string
```

Comment: No answers for this problem?